# Newest C++ compiler in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013, c++14, visual-studio-2015

In my early Linux days things were easy: I just could install the newest gcc-compiler and everything was fine. In contrast, Visual Studio confuses me a bit with it's [various download options](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs), whereas all I want is the newest C++ compiler in order to apply C++11 and C++14 features -- and that preferably without having to download gigabites of data. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Currently I use the free version of VS 2013 with the November 2013 CTP compiler.

- How new does the compiler get when staying in VS 2013 (until the official VS 2015 comes out)?
- Are there some "good practices" for switching to VS 2015 CTP? Is there also a free version (I only recognized the Ultimate version so far)? When I install this VS 2015 CTP, do I have to download the whole official stuff again once it is released, or can I update?

Comment: CTP stands for "Community Technology Preview" - that's the "unstable" branch, essentially. If that's what you want, the bleeding edge is VS 2015 CTP. The latest "stable" is VS 2013 Update 4 (not CTP); Community edition is the most fully featured free version of that.

Comment: Generally, the recommended procedure for upgrading from CTP to "official" is to completely uninstall CTP first; upgrading from earlier CTP to a later one often requires that. Further, the [release notes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2967191) have this to say: "Although these CTPs are intended to be installed side by side together with earlier versions of Visual Studio, full compatibility for every CTP is not guaranteed." So at the most paranoid, it may be prudent to not install a CTP release on your regular development machine, but on a separate one (virtual machines are handy for that).

Comment: The C++ compiler is not broken out as a separate download, you can only get the whole shebang.  Best way to deal with that is the obvious way, don't wait for the download to finish.  Pop a bear or go to sleep or answer some SO questions :)

Comment: Under these circumstances, I decided to download the newest VS 2015 CTP version. Thank you for the overview. Another question while I await the end of the download: is there some special usability concept for the Ultimate version (the only one available)? Does it allow usage for longer than, say, 30 days?

Answer (score 2):

The VS 2015 CTP is under a preview license, so there's currently only the single edition out. When it is released, all the various editions for it will be created.

You should look into the new Community edition (currently VS 2013 Community) which is more full-featured than VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop.